# R: Storing Loop Result in a Vector

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, vector, indexing

I'm trying to run a loop that stores results in a vector. But I also need to increase the counter across a predetermined vector for the stored calculation to run properly. I'm stuck on two parts: (1) increasing the counter, and (2) storing the result of the loop in a vector.

I'm new to loops so bear with the most likely incorrect syntax below; here's what I'm working with:

```
x <- c(.01,.05,.10,.20,.25) # observed defect rates
for(i in x) {
  j <- 1
  if(x < 1){
    atmost2[] <- dbinom(0,size=10,prob=x[[j]])+
    dbinom(1,size=10,prob=x[[j]])+
    dbinom(2,size=10,prob=x[[j]]) &&
      j <- j + 1
  }
}
atmost2
```

Essentially I'd like to store the result in a new vector, atmost2, with each successive loop running across the vector values in x by increasing j; j should increase to change the prob parameter in dbinom from the predetermined vector values in x.

Can anyone help out?

Comment: The workings of the code are not clear.  Since `j <- 1` is a constant, that should be moved outside the `for` loop.  The `if(x < 1)` statement is not needed because all of the `x` values are less than 1.  The logical operator `&&` in the equation does not make sense to me.  Moreover the `j <- j + 1` term in the `if` would just be re-initialized to 1 with `j <- 1` in the loop if you keep it there.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

juljo is correct to initialize the vector before a loop, and they made some other corrections, but I think their code only works if you have already established:

```
j <- 1
```

Without that, juljo's code breaks.

Also, your code doesn't need the '&&' to work.  Just put j<-j+1 on a new line, like this (Using julgo's code)

```
j <- 1
x <- c(.01,.05,.10,.20,.25) # observed defect rates
atmost2 <- as.numeric(1:length(x))  # this initializes the vector to a predetermined length which may help with very large loops
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  
  if(x < 1){
    atmost2[i] <- dbinom(0,size=10,prob=x[j])+   # note that the double brackets are gone
      dbinom(1,size=10,prob=x[j])+
      dbinom(2,size=10,prob=x[j]) 
  }
  j <- j + 1  # I think you want j to increment outside the if statement
}
atmost2
```

This code does 'something' but there are a few warnings and I'm not sure what you are trying to do.

You could also skip the adding of the dbinoms and instead to this:

```
j <- 1
x <- c(.01,.05,.10,.20,.25) # observed defect rates
atmost2 <- as.numeric(1:length(x))  # this initializes the vector to a predetermined length which may help with very large loops
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  
  if(x < 1){
    atmost2[i] <- sum(dbinom( 0:2 , size=10,prob=x[j]))  #dbinom will give a vector that can be summed
  }
  j <- j + 1  # I think you want j to increment outside the if statement
}
atmost2
```

But I think using the j iterator might be habit from other programming languages.  Notice the same out put using a loop but without j:

```
x <- c(.01,.05,.10,.20,.25) # observed defect rates
atmost2 <- as.numeric(1:length(x))  # this initializes the vector to a predetermined length which may help with very large loops
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  
  if(x < 1){
    atmost2[i] <- sum(dbinom(0:2,size=10,prob=x[i])) 
  }
  }
atmost2
```

These all produce the same output:

```
> atmost2
[1] 0.9998862 0.9884964 0.9298092 0.6777995 0.5255928
```

But I have follow up questions:

Should atmost2 be the same length as x?

Are you using the values in x as probabilities? So, atmost2 is a sum of dbinom probabilities based on the value of x[i]?

Does it have to be a loop?  R uses vectors very well, so the apply functions may be helpful.  You might find lapply to be of use here.
?apply might start you off while
?lapply will give descriptions of the other apply functions.

So your code may look like this

```
x <- c(.01, .05, .10, .20, .25)
atmost2 <- as.numeric(1:length(x)) 

atmost2 <- lapply(x, function(x) sum(dbinom( 0:2 , size = 10, prob = x)))

atmost2   # this is a list, not a vector
```

the lapply function reads like this:

apply to items in a list, 'x', a function.

In this case, the function is an anonymous function "sum(dbinom....)"

So, apply to  each value of x the function sum(dbinom...) and return a list.

Basically, it does the loop for you.  And often times faster than a for-loop (in R).

If you need atmost2 to not be a list and instead a vector, you can:

```
unlist(atmost2)

>   unlist(atmost2)
[1] 0.9998862 0.9884964 0.9298092 0.6777995 0.5255928
```

edit based on the reminder of Rui

Using sapply, everything else is the same but the output is indeed a vector.

```
x <- c(.01, .05, .10, .20, .25)
atmost2 <- as.numeric(1:length(x)) 

atmost2 <- sapply(x, function(x) sum(dbinom( 0:2 , size = 10, prob = x)))

atmost2   # this is a vector
```

Comment: If you use `sapply` instead of `lapply` there will be no need for `unlist`. Upvote, btw.

Comment: Absolutely.  I am assuming the OP is new and from my own experience, lapply was easier to comprehend.

Comment: Brian is right, my answer had to be edited and the j needed to be replaced by an i. Obviously the `sapply` way of tackling this problem is better though.

Comment: Thanks for the responses! All were really helpful in understanding the functionality in R (I'm pretty green as you might've noticed). My follow up to your questions:

Should atmost2 be the same length as x? --> atmost2 should be the same length as x

Are you using the values in x as probabilities? --> yes
So, atmost2 is a sum of dbinom probabilities based on the value of x[i]? --> yes; the consolidation using the sum function and the sequencing from 0:2 was rad!

Does it have to be a loop? --> no; the solution using lapply and sapply were great for conciseness and consolidation

Answer (score 0):

How about calling elements like this:

```
x <- c(.01,.05,.10,.20,.25) # observed defect rates
atmost2 <- numeric() # Initialize vector before filling it in the loop
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
  if(x[i] < 1){
    atmost2[i] <- dbinom(0,size=10,prob=x[i])+
      dbinom(1,size=10,prob=x[i])+
      dbinom(2,size=10,prob=x[i])
  }
}
atmost2
```